# Rails application: SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails (Spree) application running on a Debian/Apache/Passenger server. I have just randomly started seeing the following issue when trying to access the admin area.

I have tried changing my server's hostname to 127.0.0.1, I've updated Passenger, Ruby, all gems, I also tried reinstalling httparty & omniauth with no luck.

```
D, [2015-09-10T20:22:10.169700 #4792] DEBUG -- :   Spree::Store Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `spree_stores`.* FROM `spree_stores` WHERE `spree_stores`.`default` = 1  ORDER BY `spree_stores`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
I, [2015-09-10T20:22:10.376695 #4792]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 211ms
F, [2015-09-10T20:22:10.378766 #4792] FATAL -- : 
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
  httparty (0.13.5) lib/httparty/request.rb:101:in `perform'
  httparty (0.13.5) lib/httparty/request.rb:275:in `handle_response'
  httparty (0.13.5) lib/httparty/request.rb:115:in `perform'
  httparty (0.13.5) lib/httparty.rb:522:in `perform_request'
  httparty (0.13.5) lib/httparty.rb:460:in `get'
  httparty (0.13.5) lib/httparty.rb:560:in `get'
  spree_core (3.0.0) app/models/spree/alert.rb:14:in `current'
  spree_backend (3.0.0) app/controllers/spree/admin/base_controller.rb:38:in `check_alerts'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  passenger (5.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:94:in `process_request'
  passenger (5.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (5.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  passenger (5.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  passenger (5.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:112:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Comment: In general for ServerFault to be able to help you we need an actual question which includes a question mark `?`. ...

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Please, I should add. :)

Comment: In all seriousness `SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)` is an error that occurs when a hostname can not be resolved to an ip-address, which may be a DNS problem, a typo or sometimes even  a leading or trailing white space around an otherwise valid hostname.